# Парсинг строки PHP xml

Tags: php, xmlparser

Как я могу распарсить строку в массив.
Каждый массив должен начинаться с даты.
В строке я должен находить установленную дату сообщения и вырезать все сообщение вместе с датой.
Имеется еще одна проблема. Данные приходят от 1С и при переносе строки используется символ "↵" или "↵↵" .. как их можно обрезать, и вместо них вставить обычный пробел?

**Текст**

```
02.09.2016 18:04:12, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵Регион: Москва↵Количество точек: 1↵↵26.07.2016 10:54:29, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵Регион: Москва↵Количество точек: 1↵↵20.07.2016 12:33:23, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"↵↵24.06.2016 17:41:36, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵Регион: Москва↵Количество точек: 1↵↵07.06.2016 13:58:38, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"↵↵25.05.2016 17:20:42, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵↵25.05.2016 17:20:42, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Квалифицировать клиента":↵↵
```

**Выходные данные**

```
[
 0 => 02.09.2016 18:04:12, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту": Регион: Москва Количество точек: 1
 1 => 26.07.2016 10:54:29, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту": Регион: Москва Количество точек: 1
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю данный пример парсинга вам поможет

```
<?php
$string = '02.09.2016 18:04:12, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵Регион: Москва↵Количество точек: 1↵↵26.07.2016 10:54:29, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵Регион: Москва↵Количество точек: 1↵↵20.07.2016 12:33:23, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"↵↵24.06.2016 17:41:36, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵Регион: Москва↵Количество точек: 1↵↵07.06.2016 13:58:38, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"↵↵25.05.2016 17:20:42, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":↵↵25.05.2016 17:20:42, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Квалифицировать клиента":↵↵';

$array = explode('↵↵',$string);
foreach ($array as &$str) {
    $str = str_replace('↵', '&nbsp;', $str);
}
print_r($array );

?>
```

В итоге должно получится так

```
     Array
(
    [0] = 02.09.2016 18:04:12, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":&nbsp;Регион: Москва&nbsp;Количество точек: 1
    [1] = 26.07.2016 10:54:29, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":&nbsp;Регион: Москва&nbsp;Количество точек: 1
    [2] = 20.07.2016 12:33:23, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"
    [3] = 24.06.2016 17:41:36, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":&nbsp;Регион: Москва&nbsp;Количество точек: 1
    [4] = 07.06.2016 13:58:38, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"
    [5] = 25.05.2016 17:20:42, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту":
    [6] = 25.05.2016 17:20:42, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Квалифицировать клиента":
    [7] = 
)
```